# Find the volume a solid by triple integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

We need to find the volume of the solid bounded by the $xy$-plane, the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2x$, and the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$ The volume is given by the triple integral $\int \int \int_S \,dx\,dy\,dz,$where S is the region of the bounded solid.

I am trying to use spherical co-ordinates where the integral becomes $\int \int \int_T r^2 \phi \,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$  but I am unable to set the correct bounds for the $r,\theta, \phi$ integrals. The order of integration I am trying is $\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$.

Can you suggest how to correctly setup the integral in spherical co-ordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the surfaces of interest are a cylinder and a cone, I would think that a transformation to *cylindrical* coordinates would be more suitable.  Indeed, I would shift the surfaces by $1$ unit in the $x$ direction, centering the region of integration in the $xy$-plane to the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

We'll set up the volume integration using each coordinate system, with the calculation in cylindrical coordinates serving to check the result from the application of spherical coordinates.

Using cylindrical coordinates, the cylinder of radius $ \ 1 \ $ with symmetry axis $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ $ has the equation $ \ x^2 \ - \ 2x \ + \ 1 \ + \ y^2 \ = \ 1 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ r \ = \ 2 \ \cos \theta \ $ and the cone is described by $ \ r \ = \ z \ $ .  A "slice" through the solid of interest taken parallel to the $ \ xy- $ plane looks like

[image: ![enter image description here]

The slice is symmetrical about the $ \ xz-$ plane ( $ \theta \ = \ 0 $ ) and the intersections of the cone (red) and the cylinder (blue) occur at

$$ z \ = \ 2 \cos \theta \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \theta \ = \ \pm \arccos \left( \frac{z}{2} \right) \ \ . $$

Thus, applying the symmetry of the slices, we can set up the volume integral as

$ V \ \ = \ \ 2 \ \int_0^2 \ \int_0^{\arccos(z/2)} \ \int_z^{2 \cos \theta} \ \ r \ dr \ \ d\theta \ \ dz $

$ \ \ \ \ = \ \ 2 \ · \ \frac{1}{2}  \ \int_0^2 \ \int_0^{\arccos(z/2)} \ \ (2 \cos \theta)^2 \ - \ z^2  \  \ d\theta \ \ dz   $

$ \ \ \ \ = \ \  \int_0^2 \  \ \left( \ 4 \left[ \frac{1}{2} \left( \theta \ + \sin \theta \cos \theta \right) \right] \ - \ z^2  \theta \  \right) \vert_0^{\arccos(z/2)} \ \ dz   $

[using a right triangle with angle $ \ \theta \ $ , "adjacent side" $ \ z \ $ , and hypotenuse $ \ 2 \ $ ]

$ \ \ \ \ = \ \  \int_0^2 \  \ 2 \arccos(z/2) \ + \ 2  ·  \frac{\sqrt{4 - z^2}}{2}  ·  \frac{z}{2} \ - \ z^2   \arccos(z/2) \ \ \ dz   $

$ \ \ \ \ = \ \  \left[ \ 2 z \arccos(z/2) \ - \ 2 \sqrt{4 - z^2} \ + \ \frac{1}{2} · \left(  -\frac{1}{3} (4-z^2)^{3/2}  \right) \ - \ \frac{z^2}{3}   \arccos(z/2) \ + \ \left( \frac{z^2 + 8}{9} \right) \ \sqrt{4-z^2}\ \right] |_0^2  $

$ \ \ \ \ = \ \  \left[ \ 4 \arccos(1) \ - \ 2 \sqrt{4 - 2^2} \ - \ \frac{1}{6}   · (4-2^2)^{3/2}  \ - \ \frac{2^2}{3}   \arccos(1) \ + \ \left( \frac{2^2 + 8}{9} \right) \ \sqrt{4-2^2} \ \right] $
$ \ \ \ \ \ \ - \ \left[ \ 0 · \arccos(0/2) \ - \ 2 \sqrt{4 - 0^2} \ - \ \frac{1}{6} ·  (4-0^2)^{3/2} \ - \ \frac{0^2}{3}   \arccos(0/2) \ + \ \left( \frac{0^2 + 8}{9} \right) \ \sqrt{4-0^2} \ \right]  $

$ \ \ \ \ = \ \  \left[ \ 0 \ \right]  \ - \ \left[ \ 0  \ - \ 4 \ - \ \frac{4^{3/2}}{6}  \ - \ 0 \ + \  \frac{8}{9}  · 2 \ \right] \ \ = \ \ 4 \ + \ \frac{8}{6} \ - \ \frac{16}{9} \ \ = \ \ \frac{36 \ + \ 12 \ - \ 16}{9} \ \ = \ \ \frac{32}{9} \ \ .   $

For the volume integral in spherical coordinates, the differential form is $ \ \rho^2 \ d\rho \ \ \sin \phi \ d\phi \ \ d\theta \ $ , with $ \ \rho \ $ being distance measured from the origin (rather than $ \ r  \ $ in cylindrical coordinates being measured perpendicularly from the $ \ z-$ axis), and $ \ \phi \ $ being the polar angle measured "downward" from the $ \ z-$ axis.

The surface of the cone is always at $ \ \phi \ = \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ , the $ \ xy-$ plane is at $ \ \phi \ = \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ , and a "vertical slice" through the solid of our concern at a given $ \ \theta \ $ looks like
[image: ![![enter image description here]

The expression for $ \ \rho \ $ is found from $$ \ \sin \phi \ = \ \frac{2 \cos \theta }{\rho} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \rho \ = \ \frac{2 \cos \theta }{\sin \phi} \ \ . $$

While this looks like it will be unpleasant to work with, the integration in spherical coordinates is actually *simpler* than the one above, and proves to be *separable*.  We can again exploit symmetry, this time integrating over $ \ \theta \ $ from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ , the full projection of the cylinder onto the $ \ xy-$ plane.

$ V \ \ = \ \ 2 \ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ \int_0^{2 \cos \theta \ / \sin \phi} \ \  \rho^2 \ d\rho \ \ \sin \phi \ d\phi\ \ \ d\theta  $

$ \ \ \  \ \ = \ \ 2 \ · \ \frac{1}{3}  \ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ \ \left( \frac{2 \cos \theta }{\sin \phi} \right)^3  \  \ \sin \phi \ d\phi\ \ \ d\theta   $

$ \ \ \  \ \ =  \ \frac{2}{3} \ · \ 8  \ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ \cos^3 \theta \ \ d\theta \ \ \ \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \  \left( \frac{1 }{\sin \phi} \right)^2  \   \ d\phi\ \ \ = \ \ \frac{16}{3}   \ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ \cos^3 \theta \ \ d\theta \ \ \ \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \  \csc^2 \phi   \   \ d\phi\   $

$ \ \ \  \ \ =  \  \frac{16}{3}   \ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ \cos^3 \theta \ \ d\theta \ \ · \  -\cot \phi   \  |_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{16}{3}   \ · \ \frac{2}{3}  \ · \  - ( 0  -  1 ) \ \ = \ \ \frac{32}{9} \ \ , $

with the first definite integral being one ( $ \ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ \sin^n \theta \ \ d\theta \ = \ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ \cos^n \theta \ \ d\theta \ $ ) for which there is a familiar formula.